# SSAS measure value aggregate error

Tags: ssas, olap, cube, olap-cube, ssas-2012

I have a Fact table with the following rows

[image]

When I process my cube I want results like this :
[image]

However when procession my cube I get the following results:[image]

I have fee rate (hourly rate) as a measure but it is summing the values when LineID is the same (see value highlighted in red), even though the dates and start times are different.

How can I change my Hourlyrate measure to only display the unique value and not a summation? I have tried changing the AggregationFunction to None but this gives me null values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by creating a Dimension table containing the fee rates and then used to this determine the rate

Answer (score 0):

You've done a poor job of explaining your requirements and your issue.

Anyway, I would try changing the AggregationFunction for your Coll Fee Rate measure to Max.  That will show the highest underlying value.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **AggregationFunction** for "Fee Rate" measure to **AverageOfChildren**

for more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365396.aspx

Comment: This is ok when the rate is the same for each line. However, when the rate is different I am getting one line with the sum of the rates, not a line for each rate.